# Localized Alert MSG in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Localization Resources table that has resourceType, cultureCode, resourceKey, resourceValue columns.

```
resourceType | cultureCode | resourceKey | resourceValue
Alert        | en-US       | Hello       | Hello
Alert        | es-ES       | Hello       | Hola
```

I need to create an alert msg that translates based on where the user is from (US or Spain).
I was thinking

```
alert('<asp:Localize runat="server" id="locText" meta:resourcekey="Alert">Hello</asp:Localize>');
```

Does this look right?

Comment: _Does this look right?_ Well, does it work?

Comment: hehe...I haven't tried, I thought I would ask before making any changes...there are some other changes that need to be made on the same aspx along side so I wanted to confirm this before deploying.

Comment: It certainly does not! It'll show <asp:Localize runat="server" id="locText" meta:resourcekey="Alert">Hello</asp:Localize> in the alert box not Hola! try this: alert('<%# <asp:Localize runat="server" id="locText" meta:resourcekey="Alert">Hello</asp:Localize> %>');

Comment: CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'